# Why few query_id's are not showing up in query_history?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Few query_id's which run more than 2 mins on a particular warehouse are not showing up in the table(information_schema.query_history()), but when I execute them in account usage schema from the snowflake database it shows up.
Is there any reason for that as the documentation says it should hold past 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

There is limit on the number of rows that comes up on the query_history view. The default is 100. But it can be extended till 10000. I have also faced this situation and the way I solved it is to use a different warehouse for workloads where I needed to use the query id. What was happening was, since everyone was using the same warehouse the limit of 100(and later 10000) was reaching very fast. Please read about the limit below
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html

```
RESULT_LIMIT => num
A number specifying the maximum number of rows returned by the function:

If the number of matching rows is greater than this limit, the queries with the most recent end time (or those that are still executing) are returned, up to the specified limit.

Range: 1 to 10000

Default: 100.
```

Comment: Hi Rajib, I agree even I checked this by changing the value to 10,000 still those ID's are not generating. If possible you can check from your end that any warehouse that has the query run more than 2 mins and check the Query ID in the table(information_schema.query_history()) if it generates then I might be missing something.